# JNI: NO at openCV install under Linux

Tags: java, linux, opencv, cmake

I would like to install OpenCV under Linux Mint. I tried several tutorials, but no success. By CMake configuration in the Java section I get the following list:

```
Java:                          
    ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.10.3)
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO
```

I guess I need to set the right path to JNI, but what is the right path actually? The JDK, or JVM, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in opencv tutorial and it worked for me:

> Note
>
> If CMake can’t find Java in your system set the JAVA_HOME environment
>   variable with the path to installed JDK before running it. E.g.:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle 
 cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
```

Comment: Where can I set this optionm please?

Comment: before you run the command in terminal, just type the lines above